# Django model integer increment, unique together

Tags: django, django-models

I am wanting to have the following on a model: Each time a "item" (called `product`) is added by a particular user I want to increment that users product ID (`p_id`) by one. This is different to the primary key which will increment by one for each `product` added no matter who the user is. My initial thought was to use `AutoField` but this works on the entire model.

The model will be something like:

```
class Product(models....):
    name = models.CharField(max_....)
    p_id = models.AutoField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(....)

    class Meta:
        unqiue_together = ('user', 'p_id')
```

Seeing as this will not work my next thought was to override save. To do something like.

```
def save(self, *args, **kawrgs):
    product_count = get_product_count_for_user()
    self.p_id = product_count+1
    super().save()
```

The problem here is that when a user deletes a Product the count can then become wrong for future saves.

For example:

- User adds item `p_id` is now 10
- User deletes an old item
- User adds item when I do get product count 9 is now returned
- New item is saved with `p_id` 10 (again)

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Would it be okay to you to write database specific code? If yes what DB are you using?

Comment: You could store the max_id somewhere else. Or consider, WHAT is causing your problems. Is the p_id used somewhere else? Then you might check i.e. ``Purchase.objects.aggregate(max_id=Max('p_id'))['max_id']`` to get the biggest product id used on this model. If that's too slow every time, you can use a cache, so this query is only executed, when the cache is invalid. The other option is, to store it somewhere else. ``MaxIds.filter(product_id=product.id).update(max=p_id)`` when assining a bigger id.

Comment: Sounds like you need to contain the product ID as a PK in another table.

Comment: is `user` a `ForeignKey` to a `User` model? If so add a `next_p_id` to that model, and modify the save method to copy that field to self.p_id, save self (Product instance), if successful increment next_p_id and save User instance. You may also need some defensive coding to catch and handle a database integrity error (meaning that a new Product got saved but the incremented next_p_id didn't, or more generally someone messed with things outside of your app's control).

Comment: You can add an additional attribute (BooleanField) to the model called deleted. That way you never need to delete the value from the database. your numbers will never go out of sink then.